# ¿Una función puede llamar a un Procedimiento en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, funciones, stored-procedure

Mi duda es si una función creada en mysql puedo hacer que llame un procedimiento dentro de su cuerpo.

Tengo claro que un procedimiento puede llamar a una función pero no si una función puede llamar a un procedimiento.

Es una simple duda que tengo.

Comment: Échale un ojo a [este enlace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/e04e2314-02ff-4f7b-a07e-d956e3e1195a/ejecutar-una-funcion-dentro-de-un-procedimiento-almacenado?forum=sqlserveres), creo que es lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias estuve leyendo y vi varios links en la pagina y este es el que me sirvió en concreto.                                                                            http://tecnologiaenvivo.com/mysql-procedimientos-almacenados-y-funciones/